# how to hide rows in a grid view?

Tags: asp.net

There r things to hide a column in a grid view but are there any methods by which the rows of a grid can be hidden and un hidden on a particular action. Say when a button is clicked the 1st and the 2nd row must be hidden and on another click the hidden rows must be un hidden.

Answer (score 0):

To hide rows

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tr").filter(function () {
            return $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length
        }).click(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
```